# JavaScript: setInterval and for loop explanation

Tags: javascript

i searched around for a couple of questions related to the use of the **for loop** and the **setInterval** function in JavaScript but i couldn´t find a concrete answer on why this snippet doesn´t work. Could someone explain please what´s happening under the hood and why this code doesn´t print anything at all?

```
for (let i = 0; i++; i < 10) {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log('Test');
    } , 100)
}
```

Comment: You have the condition mixed up with the increment. `i < 10; i++`

Comment: While the condition is in the wrong place, it would also be unusual to start the same `setInterval` in a loop like that.  The callback is going to run 10 times every 100ms.

Comment: Thank you all guys, sorry for the durp

Comment: One more addition, though the order of statement is mixed up, still the javascript runtime would execute the statement, but using the post increment operator in conidtion part is evaluating to false. I have updated my answer to add that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not correct. The condition needs to be the second statement in the `for` loop.

Following code should work.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10 ; i++; ) {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log('Test');
    } , 100)
}
```

**Expected Syntax `for` loop**. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>               statement

**EDIT 1:**
Though all answers (including mine) mentioned that condition needs to be second statement in the `for` loop which is correct. There is one more additional  important behavior.

*The for loop `for (let i = 0; i++; i < 10)` is actually correct in terms of grammar and even the javascript runtime executes this code.*

**But**, as in your case, if the condition is evaluating to **falsy** value then it would exit the loop.

Breaking your for loop `for (let i = 0; i++; i < 10)` into each seperate construct

1. **Initialization:** `let i = 0;` This statement initializes the value of variable i to 0.
2. **Condition:**  `i++;` Javascript evaluates the statement to check if the statement is true or not. In case of `i++` the runtime firstly checks for the current value of i which is `0` . Since `0` is considered a **falsy** value the condition evaluates to false and hence the statement is not executed. Also, `i++`  statement is a **post increment** which basically increments i and then result the original value of i.

So, if you would have written loop like below, using the intiliaztion of `i=1`, then it would have worked, though it would be running infinitely untill the browser/Server crashes as the condition `i++` would always evaluate to true. I hope that makes sense.

```
for (let i = 1; i++; i < 10) {
    // Statements would run
}
```

**Or**

```
for (let i = 0; ++i; i < 10) {   **// Pre increment**
    // Statements would run   
 }
```

**Or**

```
for (let i = 0; i=i+1; i < 10) {   **// increment i by assigment
         // Statements would run   
     }
```

Douglas Crockford in his book Good Parts mention about the usage of `++` & `--` and how it can confuse readers.

Answer (score 1):

your for loop syntax is wrong, should be

```
for (let i = 0;  i < 10; i++)
```

your setInterval code will run every 100 milliseconds for each iteration of the loop (so 10 times every 100 milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with `setInterval`, you simply malformed your `for` loop:

This:

```
for (let i = 0; i++; i < 10)
```

Should be this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

First declare the initial state of the loop, then the terminating state of the loop, then the incremental change of the loop.

[Observe](https://jsfiddle.net/co3wyvkm/).